# How can I convert a VBS script to a .EXE using Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vbscript

I need to compile a .VBS script into a Windows .EXE executable using Linux (Ubuntu)

The reason for this is when I create user accounts on Linux it modifies a VBS script for each user and that script then gets downloaded and converted to an .EXE using Windows, this is a lengthy process so if I can find a way to compile it on Linux it will save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support

This should do exactly what you want

Comment: I looked at http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics but I don't see how to compile a .vbs file.

Comment: I had my VBS converted to C# then used mono's xbuild to compile the solution after manipulation by bash scripts, works perfectly.